# Getting all text from DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, treenode

Ok, so I have this simple HTML code

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <title>Get all text</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span>This is Thomas</span>
        This is Bar
        <div id="content">
            This is Foo.
        </div>
        <span>This is Bufu</span>
    </body>
</html>
```

And i want to get all text in a variable. So i made this javascript code. But "This is Foo" and "This is Bar" are not shown.

```
var sep = '~';

$(function() {
    pageTexts = getTextFromPage();
    console.log(pageTexts);  
});

function getTextFromPage()
{
    var pageText = '';
    i = 0;
    j = 0;
    var itr = document.createTreeWalker(
        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0],
        NodeFilter.SHOW_TEXT,
        null, // no filter
        false
    );

    while(itr.nextNode()) 
    {     
        if (itr.currentNode.textContent.search("\t") && itr.currentNode.textContent.search("\n") && itr.currentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'script' && itr.currentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'noscript')
        {            
            if (i == 0)
            {
               pageText = itr.currentNode.textContent;
                i++; 
            } 
            else 
            {
                pageText = pageText + sep + itr.currentNode.textContent;
                i++;
            }       
        }
        charNumber = pageText.length;    
        elemNumber = i;      
    }
    return pageText;  
}
```

Current result is "This is Thomas~This is Bufu". And I would like to have "This is Thomas~This is Bar~This is Foo~This is Bufu". Can anyone tell me what is wrong or what should I do? I will apreciate any answer that helps me.
PS. This is for a chrome-extension and i will need to get all text from any html page even if is a very complicated page.

Comment: Your code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/QEvFF/ Can you provide a demo that represents the issue you're seeing?

Comment: Yes you`re right, it works fine in jsFiddle, not sure why not in my google chrome extension. Let me try to make a more complicated HTML.

Comment: Does it help if you get rid of some of the conditions in the first `if()` statement?

Comment: Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/smotru/MEN95/
Search in my html part for "Powerful" then go to console result and search "Powerful"

Comment: If I get rid of some conditions maybe i will get javascript content or css and i really don`t need that

Comment: I don't see "Powerful" in your demo. Did you forget to update it? Yes, I know it won't work the way you want if you get rid of some conditions, but I'm just wondering if they are causing the issue. Dropping them one by one can eliminate them as a possibility.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/smotru/MEN95/1/ sorry I`m newbie in jsFiddle

Comment: I think the answer from @Musa below is correct.

Comment: not 100% correct .. just look at console log. I don`t expect that result. I know it returns me all text but also empty spaces and new lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are filtering out the `This is Bar` and `This is Foo.` with the condition `itr.currentNode.textContent.search("\n")`.
I'm not sure what you're trying to do with the first two conditions in your if statement but `search` returns -1 when the needle isn't found and `-1` is truthy

```
        if (/*itr.currentNode.textContent.search("\t") && 
             itr.currentNode.textContent.search("\n") &&*/ 
             itr.currentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'script' && 
             itr.currentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'noscript')
```

---

```
    var text = $.trim(itr.currentNode.textContent);
    if (text.length > 0 && itr.currentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'script' && itr.currentNode.parentNode.nodeName.toLowerCase() != 'noscript')
    {            
        if (i == 0)
        {
           pageText = text;
            i++; 
        } 
        else 
        {
            pageText = pageText + sep + text;
            i++;
        }       
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QEvFF/2/

Comment: Yes you`re right, that condition are the problem, but get a look at the console response. There are a lot of empty spaces and new lines and a lot of separators "~". How can I solve it without that conditions?

Comment: you 'll have to trim the content of the text node.

Comment: Since this is for a chrome extension, you might as well just use `textContent.trim()`